# Solving second order differential equation with abstract boundary values

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Consider the following differential equation:

$$x''(t) = b^2 x(t)$$

with $x(t_0)=x_0$ and $x(t_f)=x_f$.

The solution is given by $x(t)= c_1e^{-bt} + c_2e^{bt}$.
If I would rewrite the general solution, I could also state: $x(t)= c_1\cosh(bt) + c_2\sinh(bt)$.

How can I incorporate the boundary conditions s.t. I arrive at the following solution:

$$x(t)=\frac{\sinh(b(t-t_0))x_f+\sinh(b(t_f-t))x_0}{\sinh(b(t_f-t_0))}?$$

How can I eliminate the $\cosh$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just so happens. Start with $$x(t) = c_1e^{-bt} +c_2e^{bt}.$$ Apply the boundary conditions and solve for the coefficients: $$\pmatrix{c_1\\c_2} = \pmatrix{e^{-bt_0}&e^{bt_0}\\e^{-bt_f}&e^{bt_f}}^{-1} \pmatrix{x_0\\x_f},$$ where $$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}^{-1} = \dfrac 1 {ad-bc} \pmatrix{d&-b\\-c&a}.$$ Then substitute back at  $$x(t) = \pmatrix{c_1&c_2} \pmatrix{e^{-bt}\\e^{bt}}.$$ Perform all operations up to this point: $$x(t) = \dfrac 1 {e^{b(t_f-t_0)}-e^{b(t_0-t_f)}} \pmatrix{x_0&x_f} \pmatrix{e^{b(t_f-t)}-e^{b(t-t_f)}\\-e^{b(t_0-t)}+e^{b(t-t_0)}}.$$ All those expressions are of the form $$e^z-e^{-z}=2\sinh(z).$$ Can you fill in the details?

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it:)